# How to use flatten with join in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is my tables in `Snowflake`.

Let's say this is `table1` which gives me some results.

```
select distinct c.stocknumber AS StockNumber 
from table1 as c
where c.currentstatus = 'Sold'
```

This is `table2` where this query works.

```
select distinct stock_number AS StockNumber 
from table2 as r, LATERAL FLATTEN(input => r.line_items) as value
where r.created_date_time::date > TO_DATE('2023-12-04') 
-- and r.created_date_time::date < TO_DATE('2024-02-26'))
and (value:reconciliationStatus::string != 'Matched')
and array_size(r.payment_items) > 0
```

Now when I do `join` here like this then it works:

```
select distinct c.stocknumber
from table1 as c
join table2 as r on r.stock_number = c.stocknumber
where r.created_date_time::date > TO_DATE('2023-12-04')
and ARRAY_SIZE(r.payment_items) > 0 
and c.currentstatus = 'Sold'
```

But `table2` has one column which is JSON data and I want to fetch one value out of it and use it in this join but it gives me `Error: invalid identifier 'R.STOCK_NUMBER'`

```
select distinct c.stocknumber
from table2 as r 
     , lateral flatten(input => r.line_items) as value
join table1 as c on r.stock_number = c.stocknumber
where r.created_date_time::date > TO_DATE('2023-12-04')
     and (value:reconciliationStatus::string != 'Matched')
and ARRAY_SIZE(r.payment_items) > 0 
and c.currentstatus = 'Sold'
```

How to use `lateral flatten` in `join` as mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving `lateral flatten` to the final statement worked for me, instead of sandwiching it between a regular inner join :)

Also, I'd consider not using "value" as an alias for the total output of the `flatten` function as one of the column outputs from `flatten` is called `value`:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten#output

See below which worked for me:

```sql
select distinct c.stocknumber
from table2 as r 
join table1 as c on r.stock_number = c.stocknumber
, lateral flatten(input => r.line_items) as value
where r.created_date_time::date > TO_DATE('2023-12-04')
     and (value:reconciliationStatus::string != 'Matched')
and ARRAY_SIZE(r.payment_items) > 0 
and c.currentstatus = 'Sold'
```